# Unpredictable / inconsistent outcomes in writing and getting counter data to Firestore database

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, actions-on-google

Currently I'm creating a Google Action game. I want to give users extra points when they have a higher loginstreak. So if a user logs in 2 times, and he gives the correct answer, he should receive 2 points instead of 1. 3 logins = 3 points etc.

For this, I have a weeklysuccescount (# of correct answers in a week) and a loginstreakcount. When I test my app, it provides inconsistent outputs. So instead of granting me 2 points at my second login, it only provides me 1. During another test doesn't grant any points at all and my total points stay the same as before.

When I log 'loginstreakcount', the value differs from the value in the database. In fact, most of the time it shows 1 login less.

I searched online for this problem and I found that it might have to do with the limitation of Firestore 1 QPS per document. However, I don't know if this is the real problem.

```
const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(payload.email)     
userRef.update({loginstreak: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)})                                         
const getuser = userRef.get()
return getuser
.then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
      } else {




        if (doc.data().loginstreak === 2) {
          userRef.update({weeklysuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)})
          conv.add('Hooray')
          console.log("If statement 2")
          conv.close('bye')
        }

        else if (doc.data().loginstreak === 3) {
          userRef.update({weeklysuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(2)})
          conv.add('Hooray')
          console.log("If statement 3")
          conv.close('bye')
        }

        else if (doc.data().loginstreak === 4) {
          userRef.update({weeklysuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(3)})
          conv.add('Hooray')
          console.log("If statement 4")
          conv.close('bye')
        }

        else if (doc.data().loginstreak === 5) {
          userRef.update({weeklysuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(4)})
          conv.add('Hooray')
          console.log("If statement 5")
          conv.close('bye')
        }

        else if (doc.data().loginstreak === 6) {
          userRef.update({weeklysuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(5)})
          conv.add('Hooray')
          console.log("If statement 6")
          conv.close('bye')
        }

        else if (doc.data().loginstreak === 7) {
          userRef.update({weeklysuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(6)})
          conv.add('Hooray')
          console.log("If statement 7")
          conv.close('bye')
        }

        else {                              
          userRef.update({weeklysuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)})
          console.log('Loginstreak: ' + doc.data().loginstreak)
          conv.add('Hooray')
          conv.close('bye')
        }
      }})
```

UPDATE:

I tried to implement the answer, but in the DB the score count is valid, however, in the Action it speaks a wrong score. So, the promise does not seem to work out yet. Here is my updated code:

```
const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(payload.email)     

                        return userRef.update({loginstreak: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)})
                        .then(() => {    

                        const getuser = userRef.get()
                        return getuser
                        .then(doc => {
                            if (!doc.exists) {
                                console.log('No such document!');
                              } else {


                                if (doc.data().loginstreak === 2) {
                                  return userRef.update({wekelijkssuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)})                                     
                                  .then(() => {
                                  conv.add('Hooray')
          console.log("If statement 2")
          conv.close('bye')
                                })
                                }

                                else if (doc.data().loginstreak === 3) {
                                  return userRef.update({wekelijkssuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(2)}) 
                                  .then(() => {
                                  conv.add('Hooray')
          console.log("If statement 3")
          conv.close('bye')
                                })
                                }

                                else if (doc.data().loginstreak === 4) {
                                  return userRef.update({wekelijkssuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(3)}) 
                                  .then(() => {
                                  conv.add('Hooray')
          console.log("If statement 4")
          conv.close('bye')
                                })
                                }

                                else if (doc.data().loginstreak === 5) {
                                  return userRef.update({wekelijkssuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(4)}) 
                                  .then(() => {
                                  conv.add('Hooray')
          console.log("If statement 5")
          conv.close('bye')
                                })
                                }

                                else if (doc.data().loginstreak === 6) {
                                  return userRef.update({wekelijkssuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(5)}) 
                                  .then(() => {
                                 conv.add('Hooray')
          console.log("If statement 6")
          conv.close('bye')
                                })
                                }

                                else if (doc.data().loginstreak === 7) {
                                  return userRef.update({wekelijkssuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(6)}) 
                                  .then(() => {
                                  conv.add('Hooray')
          console.log("If statement 7")
          conv.close('bye')
                                })
                                }

                                else {                              
                                  return userRef.update({wekelijkssuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)}) 
                                  .then(() => {
                                  console.log('Loginstreak: ' + doc.data().loginstreak)
                                  conv.add('Hooray')

          conv.close('bye')
                                }) 
                                } 
                              }}) })
```

Comment: Are your lines of code to be executed in sequence? I have the feeling that the line `getuser.then()` should execute only when the asynchronous `userRef.update({})`above is finished. With your code, this may not be the case because you are not waiting that the promise returned by the `update()` method resolves.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `update` method is not a synchronous operation. Like with the `getuser` constant, `update` returns a Promise. It is possible that your function stops running before the update is complete, resulting in a data discrepancy.

Switching your implementation to use async/await, or Promises, should allow the update to complete before proceeding.

```
app.intent('intent name', conv => {
  return userRef.update({weeklysuccescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)})
    .then(() => {
        conv.add('Hooray')
        console.log("If statement 2")
        conv.close('bye')
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nick. However, when I change this in the code I got the following error in the logs: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler? How can I solve this?

Comment: You may want to make sure your function returns a promise, ie. `return userRef....`